# How to find the particular text stored in the file "data.bin" and is human readable string starting with several "=" signs

Tags: command-line

The line I seek is stored in the file data.bin and is human readable starting with several "=" signs

How do I go about finding that particular line using linux?

Comment: Have you searched something ? What have you tried ? What fails ?

Comment: Is are you looking for a whole line of the file?  If not, then how can the *end* of your target text be recognized?  And may the target text span multiple lines?

Comment: You might try a combination of [`strings`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?apropos=0&q=strings&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8.1.0&arch=default&format=html) and `grep`

Comment: John Bollinger im looking for the string in the file

Comment: @Gilles Quenot, i know i have to use man strings but not sure how to

Comment: `strings data.bin | grep '==='` would be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
grep -a '^===' data.bin
```

Works with BSD & GNU `grep`

From

```
man grep
```

> -a, --text
> Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.

---

Another solution, because your line is composed of human and binary bytes:

```
strings data.bin | grep '==='
```

Comment: when i run this command nothing happens, but when i run grep -a '===' data.bin             then it returns non human readable strings, so how do i make it only return human readable strings

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: the other solution tells me that -b is an invalid string option

Comment: Option removed...

Comment: Does this fits your needs ?